# Storing an int value into a text file, and reading it?

Tags: java, file, int, text-files, storage

I am making a small points game, which includes a Timer, which adds the points with 1 every second. Your goal is to create as much points as possible. But, I need a way to store the points (an int value), into a txt file, or maybe a safer way. I also need a way to read the points from the file and put the stored int into my program, I know how to create a file, I created one already.

Okay, I got one more small questions, how would I make it create the file if you close the program down, and not when you start the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this homework?

Many many websites on writing and reading files. For example, look at

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42

Comment: No, programming is my hobby, and I want to learn as most as I can.

Answer (score 1):

For simple UserCases like mentioned above, Create/Read properties file using [java.util.Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) instead of handling all aspects of file handling manually. You will just need to convert (Parse) the `int` from `String`.

Moreover you get the flexibility to be easily load it from classpath or filesystem.

Look at the `load(...)` & `store(...)` to Read and Save the file respectively.
And `getProperty()` & `setProperty()` to read and create/update value for given key.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into IOUtils by the Apache Commons folks.

http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.3.2/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

```
public void saveInt(String filename, int num) {
    FileUtils.write(new File(filename), num + "\n");
}

public int loadInt(String filename) {
    return Integer.parseInt(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(filename)).trim());
}
```

Comment: How would I use this? It can't find FileUtils.